# Is it possible to configure each instance in an AWS AutoScalingGroup with a IAM permission based on each instance ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I want to create a number of EC2 instances via an AutoScalingGroup using CDK.

```
AutoScalingGroup ec2Asg = AutoScalingGroup.Builder.create(this, "Ec2Asg")
                                                  .role(myEc2InstanceProfileRole)
                                                  ... further config here ...
                                                  .build();
```

If possible, I'd like to restrict each instance in the ASG to only be able to access certain resources where the instance's ID forms part of the resource. For example:

```
arn:aws:ssm:REGION:ACCOUNT:parameter/<INSTANCE ID>/*
```

How is best to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this would not be possible for what you're trying to achieve. The IAM permissions for an EC2 instance are not assigned to the instance itself, they are instead attached to an IAM entity (such as the instances IAM role).

SSM parameters do support a [hierarchy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-su-organize.html) so you can create a parameter such as `arn:aws:ssm:REGION:ACCOUNT:parameter/InstanceRole/i-1234567/parameter` and then limit the IAM role to only access resources which match the pattern `arn:aws:ssm:REGION:ACCOUNT:parameter/InstanceRole/`.

By doing this you can at least limit the scope for your instances in the same ASG. Also be aware that the parameters themselves would still be accessible for any IAM resources with the permissions granted to them.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's very help to understand why it's not possible.

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)